# Error, Object(...) is not a function, when using BrowserRouter from reacr-router-dom

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

`node_modules`, `react-router-dom` has issue, I have deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled `react-router-dom`, but the same thing happens, it seems `react-router-dom` has an issue (maybe a missing function). How do I fix it?

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: It is difficult to read code in image. So, please use code instead of picture. And, it is OK to show the picture of error messages. What's the version of **React** and **react-router-dom**?